# Why is it possible to change variables in infinite sums?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I was working on the following problem:
Sum the series $$\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{m^2n}{3^m(m3^n + n3^m)}$$

**Solution**

Let $S= \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{m^2n}{3^m(m3^n + n3^m)}$. We can rewrite this as $$\frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 \cdot (S)$$This is equivalent to writing out 2 copies of the double sum itself, hence we have $$\frac{1}{2} \Big[ \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{m^2n}{3^m(m3^n + n3^m)} + \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2m}{3^n(n3^m + m3^n)} \Big]$$ Notice that for the RHS expression we have interchanged the variables(Fairly standard trick). Now we want to be able to combine both of these expressions into a single expression. To do so we must make the denominators the same. Hence, we multiply the denominator and numerator of the LHS expression by $3^n$, similarly for the RHS we multiply by $3^m$, therefore: $$\frac{1}{2} \Big[ \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{m^2n \cdot {\color{blue} 3^n}}{{\color{blue} 3^n} \cdot 3^m(m3^n + n3^m)} + \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2m \cdot {\color{blue} 3^m}}{{\color{blue} 3^m} \cdot 3^n(n3^m + m3^n)} \Big]$$ Simplifying and factoring we get that $$\frac{1}{2} \Big[ \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{3^{n}m^{2}n + 3^{m}n^{2}m}{3^n3^m(m3^n + n3^m)} \Big]$$$$ = \frac{1}{2} \Big[ \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{nm(3^{n}m + 3^{m}n)}{3^{n}3^{m}(m3^n + n3^m)} \Big]$$ Now notice that both expressions in the numerator and denominator are equal, thus we can cancel them out leaving $$ \frac{1}{2} \Big[ \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{nm}{3^{n}3^{m}} \Big]$$ We can now extract the sums to get a single sum each $$\frac{1}{2} \Big[ \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \frac{m}{3^m} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{3^{n}} \Big]$$ Let us now inspect the series on the RHS. The first few terms of the series are $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{3^{n}} = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{9} + \frac{3}{27} + \frac{4}{81} + \cdots$$ This is not a geometric series, so we need to rely upon a little formatting adjustments. We can write the series out in rows like so

[image]

These are all geometric so it is easy to evaluate each one line by line. The first two lines for example would be $\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1 - \frac{1}{3}}$, $\frac{\frac{1}{9}}{1 - \frac{1}{3}}$. Therefore what we essentially have is $$\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1 - \frac{1}{3}} \Big( \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{27} + \cdots \Big)$$ This then evaluates to $$\frac{3}{2} \Big( \frac{1}{2} \Big) = \frac{3}{4}$$ \

Taking a look at our sum $$\frac{1}{2} \Big[ \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \frac{m}{3^m} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{3^{n}} \Big]$$ Notice how the series we just evaluated is the same as the LHS? This means that we can now write out our final answer to be $$\boxed{\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{m^2n}{3^m(m3^n + n3^m)} = \frac{1}{2} \Big[\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \frac{m}{3^m} \Big( \frac{3}{4} \Big)  \Big] = \frac{1}{2} \Big( \frac{3}{4} \Big)^2 = \frac{9}{32}}$$

**Question**

As per the title, why does interchanging variables work?

Comment: I believe the Fubini-Tonelli theorem is at work here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Fubini%E2%80%93Tonelli_theorem

Comment: Changing the variable names is a trivial step and can be done formally for any bound variable whose name isn't currently in use.  The only non-trivial part, referenced by Raul above, is that in the same step the solution interchanges _limits_ by swapping the series summations.  That requires something as powerful as Fubini-Tonelli.

Comment: It is always possible to write $$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(m,n)$$ as $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty f(n,m).$$  This type of step is just formally renaming the indices.  Note, however, that the solution has done more than interchange variables... It also rearranges the order of summation, changing it further to $$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n,m).$$  It's this last step which needs Fubini-Tonelli or something similar, not the interchange of variable names.

Comment: @BrianMoehring That makes sense, thanks.

Comment: Related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434426/curious-double-sum-identity