# How to find this summation $\sum\limits_{m = 1}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{m^2n}{(m3^n + n3^m)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I wander in our community and find [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4591800/why-is-it-possible-to-change-variables-in-infinite-sums). And it was solved by using symmetry property (adding two version of itself) and a trick to remove denominator. I wonder how we can evaluate this sum but we remove $3^m$ from denominator, means:
$$\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{m^2n}{(m3^n + n3^m)}.$$

I followed the path by adding the second version of itself like this:

$$\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{m^2n}{(m3^n + n3^m)}+\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2m}{(m3^n + n3^m)}.$$ But, now I can't remove denominator. I tried to multiply by $(3^m+3^n)$ but it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should put the sum you want to evaluate in the title of the question - and not the one you've already seen evaluated elsewhere.

Comment: @user170231 Thank you so much, I forgot that, edited.

Comment: I'd wager this isn't solvable. The original sum was constructed to be symmetric in a way such that it simplified (perhaps by working backward), but this one lacks any such symmetry. Just trying to sum over one of the variables then the other is at best going to give a sum of some generalized digamma-type functions, so there would have to remain a really clever symmetry here to solve this.

Comment: As added data, Mathematica can evaluate the original sum in closed form, but doesn't know how to deal with this modified sum.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thank you, I agree with you about the origin problem, by removing one term, it seems harder than I thought, even with CAS can't find a closed form for this.

Comment: With some manipulations, I rearranged it into $$\sum_{s=2}^{\infty} \frac{s}{2} \sum_{m=1}^{s-1} \frac{1}{\frac{3^m}{m} + \frac{3^{s-m}}{s-m}}$$ If someone finds it useful, I can later add the steps I took to get here